# CSS sheet inside project folder in visual studio 2017 not connecting to web page when using classes in tags

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a ASP.NET web application that will be a property review survey for home owners. I have written my own CSS sheet (StyleSheet1.css) for the survey web page. However, it doesn't seem like the CSS sheet is connecting and updating the style of a div tag with class name "popup-contact" when I run a demo.

Please note the entire survey is contained with in form tags. I have added StyleSheet1.css to the header and it still didn't work. On manually entering the style inside the div tag though, it does seem to work. I also noticed that for all the classes associated with tags outside of the form tags, the associated style details in StyleSheet1.css work. So is this an issue of the style sheet not connecting to elements inside the form tags?

Here's the header:

```
<head>
    ...... Other sheets and scripts......
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/StyleSheet1.css">

    <title>Real Estate</title>
</head>
```

And here's the body:

```
<body>
<div>
............TOP NAVBAR HTML...................
</div>
<div>
<ul>........ SIDE NAVBAR HTML..........</ul>
<div>
<form name="property_review" method="post" onsubmit="return 

validate_form()">
........... SURVEY CONTENT HTML.........
<div class="popup-contact">Hi there</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here's my entry in StyleSheet1.css for the class "popup-contact":

```
.popup-contact {
    float: right;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Double check your path - `~/` is the unix way of pointing to your users root directory - if the css file is in the same folder as your html file, just its name `href="StyleSheet1.css"` is enough. Do you get a 404 for stylesheet?

Comment: I tried only href="StyleSheet1.css" but it gave the same result. And no, I don't get any sort of error with the stylesheet.

Comment: never mind it did work.